# does laravel mix compilation removes old files when error occurs?

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, laravel-mix, npm-scripts

I have my assets resources compiled and copied to `public` directory.

Later, I added few assets, registered them on `webpack.mix.js` and run `npm run dev`.

But then I stumbled into some npm error.

So my question is since the compilation is not successful, will the resource files that were previously in `public` directory be deleted?

Comment: Don't get this the wrong way, but that's something you could easily look up/check yourself. Is your `public` folder empty after you get that error? (Why should old files be deleted on a npm error?)

Comment: @kerbholz the thing is, I get newly added assets in public dir. but other assets might not have been compiled and copied since the error. There are tons and hard to tell.
Hence the post.